# Cannot start Kali Linux in Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox

MacBook Pro, Yosemite 10.10, 64-bit, 4 GB RAM, 100 GB free on HD.

1. Have downloaded VirtualBox 5.0.8.dmg and kali-linux-2.0-amd64.iso
2. Double-clicked the dmg to install VBox and all goes well with "New" and "Settings", etc.
3. Link "Storage" to the iso file
4. Press "Start" and get a "Critical Error" message with no details as to what that critical error is.

I never get to the window that says "Kali Linux" and then (if I remember), it's something like "Graphical Install". Never even get there.

I'm no expert at this but I'm about 99% sure all Settings are OK. I've tried a complete uninstall, downloading the files all over again, and reinstall with the same problem.

Any tips as to what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Download your ISO from [Offensive Security Page](https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-vmware-arm-image-download/),  they have built special images for installing kali on Virtual Machines.

I had similar problems getting the normal ISO to install on Virtual Box, but then tried that link and didn't have a problem.

Only thing I remember having to check was the Virtual Disk size.  It needs to more than 12GB for some reason.  My Virtual Box install of Kali on this computer has a 30GB disk, and almost 9GB is used.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks heaps for that. Downloaded from offensive security and it worked. The only added thing was that the file was in .ova format and I sure didn't know what to do with that, but a little digging produced the solution: In VBox > File > Import Appliance. Worked like a charm. I'm up and running.